# Why do we need singletons to be closed in the definition of Normal/Regular spaces?

Tags: general-topology

In the book of *Topology* by Munkres, at page 193, it is given that

> **Definition.** Suppose that one-point sets are closed in X. Then X is said to be regular if for each pair consisting of a point x and a
>   closed set B disjoint from x, there exist disjoint open sets
>   containing x and B, respectively. The space X is said to be normal if
>   for each pair A, B of disjoint closed sets of X, there exist disjoint
>   open sets containing A and B, respectively.
>
> It is clear that a regular space is Hausdorff, and that a normal space
>   is regular. (**We need to include the condition that one-point sets be
>   closed as part of the definition of regularity and normality in order
>   for this to be the case.** A two-point space in the indiscrete topology
>   satisfies the other part of the definitions of regularity and
>   normality, even though it is not Hausdorff.)

But, how does assuming one-point sets are closed allow regular (normal) space to be Hausdorff(regular) ?

Comment: Because you can take B={y}, a different point, in your definition of regular.

Comment: @Gaffney In case when $B= \{y\}$ is open ? I didn't full get it .

Comment: If it's open then you can't conclude that the space is Hausdorff.  You don't conclude anything.

Comment: @Gaffney Yes, I know that, but I still don't understand what are you trying to say in your first comment.

Comment: @Gaffney Why did you deleted your answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further considerations:

(i). Consider Sierpinski space $S=\{x,y\}$ with $x\ne y,$ where $S,\emptyset,$ and $\{x\}$ are open but $\{y\}$ is not open. If $A, B$ are disjoint closed subsets of $S$ then at least one of $A, B$ is empty so $A,B$ are covered by disjoint open sets. But $S$ does not satisfy the condition for regularity:  $x$ does not belong to the closed subset $\{y\}$ but the only open set covering $\{y\}$ is the whole space $S$.

(ii). Let $X$ be a normal space. Let $p\in X$ and let $Y$ be a closed subset of $X$ with $p\not \in Y.$ Since $X$ is a $T_1$ space (one-point subsets are closed), the sets $\{p\}, Y$ are closed and disjoint. So, since $X$ is normal, there are disjoint open sets with $\{p\}\subset U$ and $Y\subset V. $ That is, $p\in U$ and $Y\subset V.$ So $X$ is regular.

Comment: Sierpinski space is useful for many examples and counter-examples.

Answer (score 2):

If $x \neq y$ then $\{y\}$ is a closed set adn $x \notin \{y\}$ so there exist disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $x \in U$ and $\{y\} \subset V$. This shows that the space is Hausdorff.